# Is there a firefox plugin to switch different cookies?

Tags: cookies, firefox-extensions

So I can switch through different accounts ?

Answer (score 4):

In one session? I don't think so.
You should create two (or more) profiles in the Profile Manager, and create separate shortcuts for the profiles. Also, there are plugins to change the title.

So if you put Prof1, Prof2 icons to desktop, and when they launch, it'll show Prof1, and Prof2 in the title, so you will know which is which.

Answer (score 1):

There was addon called [Cookie Pie](http://www.nektra.com/products/cookiepie-tab-firefox-extension) that allows to switch between two sets of cookies for each page, but is is compatible only with 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

CookieSwap Addon was exactly the thing you were looking for. But unfortunately, it is compatible only until Firefox 3.6 (at the time of writing this). You may check it's page at - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookieswap/